# Как проверить правильно ли введена дата?

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день, задача следующая: В WinForms дан текстбокс в который должна вводиться дата в формате YYYY-MM-DD, как проверить что дата введена в правильном виде?

Comment: Используйте `DateTimePicker` вместо `TextBox` и не мучайтесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static bool TextIsDate(string text)
{
    var dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    DateTime scheduleDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, dateFormat, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out scheduleDate))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Проверка, что дата введена в правильном виде

```
if (TextIsDate(textBox.Text))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Текст является датой");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Текст не является датой");
}
```